# Why can't find all paths after upgrade mac os?

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, zsh

My mac is macOS catalina. I upgraded my system yesterday and the version is 10.15.6 now.

A lot of things changed:

1 virtual environment:
I installed virtualenv and installed jupyter notebook inside the virtualenv. After upgrading, when I run "jupyter notebook", system tells me:

"zsh:/users/.../jupyter: bad interpreter: /users/.../python: no such file or directory"

And other library such numpy pandas etc. all report the same error

2 There is a new directory "relocated items" with one pdf says"During the last macOS upgrade or file migration, some of your files couldn't be moved to their new locations.This folder contains these files."

3 I wanted to uninstall virtualenv and the system tells me I haven't installed. I reinstall virtualenv  again and the system still tells me "no such file or directory"

what should I do now?

Comment: The previous `bashrc` and `bash_profile` are not migrated by default. Can you source them and retry once?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer problems; [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to ask. Also, do the files (/users/.../jupyter etc) actually exist? Did they get moved to the "relocated items" directory?

Comment: @Gordon Davisson /users/.../jupyter etc actually exist, didn't move to "relocated items" directory

Comment: @Ayushya, your advice is a little mouthful, do I run "source  .bashrc" and just ok? I haven't learnt shell

Comment: yes @andysun `source ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bash_profile` and then run `jupyter notebook`

Comment: @Ayushya system tells me:" zsh: /users/sunandy/.bashrc:no such file or directory" . Then I use "chsh -s /bin/bash" change to bash shell and get the same result

Comment: If the system says _no such file or directory_, I would conclude that there is indeed no such file. Did you verify it with `ls -l /users/sunandy/.bashrc`